# What could be a good project to realize neural network in hardware (VLSI) for a beginner?

Tags: cmos, vlsi

As a beginner how can I start implementing neural network using CMOS technology. I have come across implementing neural nets that mimic basic gates.

Comment: There's no beginner-accessible CMOS manufacture technology, so actually making anything is going to be a long and expensive hill to climb.

Comment: When you say you want to implement a net in hardware, what part are you actually refering too? The parralelism required during training?

Comment: I understand that it will be a long hill to climb but I want a start for that journey and I don't know how to begin.

Comment: @AdilMalik I am wondering about the implementation of activation functions for the neural nets in CMOS and seeing how it functions or trying to build a non linear arithmetic circuit to get the EPSP.

Comment: Then your question really isnt specific to neural nets? You essentially want to know how to implement a mathematical function in hardware.

Comment: You need to realize that there isnt really anything too special about the actual neural net that needs specific hardware. When you hear about companies using custom asics for neural nets almost all of the time that hardware does not implement the actual neural net, rather it invokes parralelism to speed the its training.

Comment: @AdilMalik As a part of bigger picture which is to realize the functioning of human brain, I believe functioning of neuron must be mapped on hardware with good accuracy. So I had those ideas of implementing mathematical models which are analogous to synapse , cell body of neuron.

Comment: Youll be suprised to know there isnt much to 1 artificial neuron. It is simply a few multiplications, additions, and an activation function. The whole point is being able to implement these in software. For example a conventional feed forward network isnt some glorious brain like connection of special logic hardware. Its simply the mathematical operations i listed above. So making hardware for it will simply mean designing adders, multipliers with floating point support.

Comment: @AdilMalik oh I see. Then what is your suggestion.

Comment: see my answer..

Answer (score 2):

As a beginner it is very easy to have broad ambitions such as "i want to implement a neural net in hardware". You must carefully define what exactly do you mean by that. If you are referring to a feed forward net with backtracking you must realise there isnt really any need for a fancy dedicated hardware for the actual net.

A trained neural net can be thought of as a look up table, so a general purpose cpu is sufficient.
Also the neural net itself (conventional feedforward) is really not some glorious arrangement of brain like logic that needs specialised hardware. Rather it is simply an arrangement of many adders, multipliers and a threshold function (which is also consisting of adders, multipliers etc) with floating point support. So if you really want to build it in hardware, you need to implement the aforementioned mathematical functions much like an ALU would.

Now if you want to implement hardware that speeds up training by invoking parallelism, there is some scope here. Start with an FPGA, implement floating point units, threads etc. This is not a beginners project.

If the main goal of this project is to have fun with training a neural network and understanding it on a low level your best bet as a beginner is to do it in software avoiding mainstream libraries such as the famous Tensorflow. If you want to do it low level, try implementing a Neural Net in C++ (or any other language for that matter) and train it using a graphic card using CUDAs API (Nvidia only) to recognise human handwriting from the MNIST database. It is low level enough to have real fun.